# Putting text into a textarea via a jQuery click event?

Tags: jquery

Say I have a text area like this:

```
<textarea id="comment_mc" name="comment" class="comment" rows="4" cols="30"></textarea>
```

And divs like this:

```
<div class="fees-item fees-item-odd">
訂婚,歸寧或補請午宴,晚宴<br />
妝前保養<br />
造型改變2套<br />
上水粉,協助nu bra穿著<br />
宴客補妝<br />
媽媽妝1 親友淡妝1(不含髮型)<br />
新郎淡妝(含髮型)</p>
<h4>16000NTD</h4>
<a class="fees-purchase" href="">Purchase</a>
</div>
<div class="fees-item fees-item-even">
結婚全程(三套造型)<br />
妝前保養<br />
迎娶造型<br />
進場造型2套<br />
上水粉協助NU Bra穿著<br />
宴客補妝<br />
媽媽妝1 (不含髮型)<br />
新郎淡妝(含髮型) </p>
<h4>18000NTD</h4>
<a class="fees-purchase" href="">Purchase</a>
</div>
```

Is there anyway to put the text of a `.fees-item` div into the `textarea` when the user clicks on its `fees-purchase` link?

Comment: Look at the related questions.

Comment: The markup is invalid, where are opening `<p>` tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you meant to wrap the text you wanted moved into the textarea in a `<p>` tag rather than have incorrect markup

```
$('.fees-purchase').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#comment_mc').val($(this).siblings('p').text());
})
```

The markup should then be

```
<div class="fees-item fees-item-odd">
<p>
訂婚,歸寧或補請午宴,晚宴<br />
妝前保養<br />
造型改變2套<br />
上水粉,協助nu bra穿著<br />
宴客補妝<br />
媽媽妝1 親友淡妝1(不含髮型)<br />
新郎淡妝(含髮型)</p>
<h4>16000NTD</h4>
<a class="fees-purchase" href="">Purchase</a>
</div>
<div class="fees-item fees-item-even">
<p>
結婚全程(三套造型)<br />
妝前保養<br />
迎娶造型<br />
進場造型2套<br />
上水粉協助NU Bra穿著<br />
宴客補妝<br />
媽媽妝1 (不含髮型)<br />
新郎淡妝(含髮型) </p>
<h4>18000NTD</h4>
<a class="fees-purchase" href="">Purchase</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try use snippet below:

```
$('.fees-purchase').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('textarea').html($(this).parent('.fees-item').text().replace($(this).html(),''));
});
```

You find the demo at **[JSFIDDLE.NET](http://jsfiddle.net/EemNa/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$(function () {
    $('.fees-item').on('click', '.fees-purchase', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        //console.log($(this).closest('div').text())
        $('#comment_mc').val($(this).closest('div').find('p').text());
    });
});
```

See demo in http://jsfiddle.net/tamilcselvan/xGpZf/1/

Answer (score 1):

maybe you dont use `<br>` but you can use `<p>`

> ```
> <head>
>     <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
>     <script>
>         $("document").ready(function(){
>             p = $('.fees-item').find('p');
>
>             $('.fees-purchase').click(function(){
>                 $('textarea').text(p);    
>             });
>
>         });
>     </script>
> </head>
> <body>
>     <textarea class="comment_mc"></textarea>
>     <div class="fees-item">
>         <p>1</p>
>         <p>1</p>
>         <p>1</p>
>     </div>
>     <a href="" class="fees-purchase">Purchase</a>
> </body>
> ```